# How to use docker container as a proxy?

Tags: python, docker, mitmproxy

I have the following docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mitmproxy:
    image: johnmccabe/mitmweb
    container_name: mitmproxy
    command: --cadir /ca --wiface 0.0.0.0 
    restart: always
    ports:
        #- "8080:8080"
        - "8081:8081"

  python:
    image: python
    build: ./python-socks-example
    command: python3 /home/project/socks-example.py
    volumes:
      - ./python-socks-example:/home/project/
    depends_on:
       - mitmproxy
    container_name: python
    restart: always
```

I want my python HTTP requests to go through mitmproxy on the other container. Here's the python code:

```
import requests
import time

while(True):
    time.sleep(5)
    print("gonna connect")
    resp = requests.get('http://google.com', 
                    proxies=dict(http='socks5://user:pass@server.com:8080',
                                 https='socks5://user:pass@server.com:8080'))
    print(resp)
    print("done")
    time.sleep(2)
```

How can I wire the network of `python` to go through `mitmproxy` container?

Comment: I think your proxy url should be `@mitmproxy:8080` instead

Comment: @drum yes if the mitmproxy were in the socks mode. But I want to actually connect to an external socks proxy but make it pass through mitmproxy just for sniffing

Comment: You probably want to use `mitmproxy/mitmproxy` and not `johnmccabe/mitmweb`.